# Slider revolution not showing all slides in slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, revolution-slider

I'm facing a strange problem in slider revolution in WordPress, I just create 6 slides in a slider, but it showing only three slides.

HTML5 videos layers exist in All the slides, I don't know why this thing happen. Help me plz

Here is link

http://smartcastle.in/

Comment: any errors on the console?

Comment: And also i just create a one slide and then i duplicate this slide, then just change the video source in it

Answer (score 3):

`<b/>` around line 370 or so - should be `<br />`